# How do I know which version of asp.net mvc one project is?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to know just by checking the asp.net mvc project what version it is.

notice that I am not talking about .net framework version...

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each project based on ASP.NET MVC consists of various number of packages (libraries, extensions, etc.). All information about versions gathered in file **packages.config** in the root of your project.

Answer (score 1):

In the "References" section in your project within the solution explorer, look for "System.Web.Mvc". Look at the properties window for this reference. You will see the version number listed under "Version".